# Get WAN IP Using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ip-address, rdp, wan

I have a Windows logon script running and am compiling a set of details that get logged when the user logons on. As this is a remote server, all logons are done via RDP. I need to get the IP address of the user who has logged on. I have used the following:

```
Function WAN_IP()
    Set objxmlHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Call objxmlHTTP.open("get", "http://checkip.dyndns.org", False)
    objxmlHTTP.Send()

    strHTMLText = objxmlHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objxmlHTTP = Nothing

    If strHTMLText <> "" Then
        varStart = InStr(1, strHTMLText, "Current IP Address:", vbTextCompare) + 19
        If varStart Then varStop = InStr(varStart, strHTMLText, "</body>", vbTextCompare)
        If varStart And varStop Then strIP = Mid(strHTMLText, varStart, varStop - varStart)
    Else
        strIP = "Unavailable"
    End If

    WAN_IP = Trim(strIP)
End Function
```

This, as expected, returns the external IP of the server itself and not the IP of the user who has connected.

Is anybody able to let me know how I get the IP of the user connected via RDP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the IP Address of the Remote Desktop Client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510093/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-desktop-client)

Comment: How do the users connect? LAN or WAN/VPN?

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks - good find! Will check it out

Comment: @Tomalak: Connecting over WAN. No VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Following the response from @MarcB I used [How to get the IP Address of the Remote Desktop Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510093/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-desktop-client) to get the idea on what to do.

I then found some example code here: http://pleasepressanykey.blogspot.com/2008/09/get-users-last-successful-and-failed.html